# is it posible to display the result of if else php statement without reloading the page

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out how does the if else statement on php display the result without reloading the page! Is this posible or not? or anything code needed to make this work on my project?
This is for my school project presentaion which the time is setted to 7:30:00 Am ! If time is equal to current time. It will display the result withour reloading the page!

This is my code but I dont have a refresh page becuase ajax didnt work!

```
<?php 
$timenow=time();
$thetime = date('g:i:s a',$timenow);
$settime = strtotime('today 7:30:00pm');
$timesetting = date('g:i:s a',$settime);
if($timesetting <= $thetime)
{
    echo "School Time";
}
else
{
    echo "Not late for school";
}
?>
```

Comment: Without AJAX, this is not possible if you need the **server** time

Comment: The title of the question is "with reloading" while your question is about "without reloading". Its little confusing.

Comment: @NicoHaase How will I do this? Are there server time date_default_timezone_set();

Comment: @AnNguyen title has been edited! Sorry! mistake on title

Comment: "becuase ajax didnt work" - so make it work and create a timer in js script. If you want to wait in php code - your page will be loading until counter == time_you_need

Comment: What do you mean by "How will I do this"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Alexey I tried ajax but the problem is I dont know how to add the value of javascript variable on php Im not into javascript yet! We are still on php

Comment: Assuming the clock of the device is correct you could do this with Javascript only, but no matter what you do, you would need some javascript, if you don't want to use a complete page reload.

Comment: @NicoHaase Im stuck on ajax which I created a time using ajax But I dont know how to add this <div id="timer"> on php which is The div id="timer"  is equal to $thetime

Comment: This is my ajax   <div id="time"></div>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(timestamp, 1000);
});

function timestamp() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'timer.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#time').html(data);
        },
    });
}
  </script>

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't put important information into the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand - you cannot use JS code by some reasons and you need to use PHP only. Taking into account this condition and omiting the factor that user experience will be much lower in this case - you can implement your idea using this code:

```
<?php
// time() is a time in seconds

// time when you should go to school in seconds
$settime = strtotime('today 7:30:00pm');

// compare this 2 times until time will be >=
while ( time() < $settime ) {
    echo "Its too early!\n";
    sleep(1);
}

// this echo will be always displayed if `$settime` point is in the past
echo "You should be in the school now!";

?>
```

P.S. In your example you are comparing 2 variables, that always store same values (same time points in seconds), but you should call `time()` function every time, because time is ticking. So its ok that your `$settime` is not changing, but current time should be changing every (milli) second.

Comment: I will try this!

Comment: Okay I understand it now

Comment: @LeinarNilotna feel free to tick an answer as a solution, if I answered to your question

Comment: Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! Its too early! You should be in the school now!  It loops mytime

Comment: @LeinarNilotna so?